# What is a full rectangular output characteristic for a power supply?

Tags: power-supply, power, power-electronics

From what I understand, a rectangular output characteristic of a power supply refers to the fact that the maximum power is achieved when Vmax and Imax occur simultaneously. Kepco has a power supply that claims "full rectangular output characteristic." Is this because this is not a common quality? That is, do most power supplies not meet this criteria?

If so, what physical or design limitations prevent a power supply from achieving a rectangular output characteristic?

Here's a link to the product: http://www.kepcopower.com/klr.htm

Comment: Here's the product: http://www.kepcopower.com/klr.htm.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is whether the supply can provide its full rated current at the max rated voltage. Since power is V x I, the worst case for power is at that point of the "rectangle".

For many supplies the curve has a parabolic section where V x I = constant. This is obviously not a rectangle!

Comment: Technically, it's a hyperbolic section :-)

Comment: Ah yes, you are correct! Parabolic is x squared. Hyperbolic is 1/x. Thank god for Wikipedia!